# Problem running react websites on TizenBrowser v1.1.2.07 on tv's

Tags: reactjs, browser

I have multiple react websites that do not render on the TizenBrowser on some tv's. Every other browser and devices there aren't any problems. I have been trying to figure out whats the problem but with no luck. Have you guys dealt with this problem? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check official docs: https://developer.tizen.org/forums/web-application-development/web-app-development-issues-react-and-webpack-tizen-tv-os-2.4

Comment: You are probably using functions or methods that are not supported by the Tizen version and you'd need a pollyfill maybe...
Have you tried on a Samsung 2019? These are the ones with better compatibility.